# Where is an explanation of the Configurations element in .NET Csproj files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When the project supports multiple build configurations, project configurations, they are entered into a Configurations element in the first PropertyGroup. Why is this, how can this property be used and is it documented?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation [Understanding the Project File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file)?

Comment: @AxelKemper Yes but there is no mention of a Configurations element.

Comment: Here "multiple build configurations" refers to " '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' " and " '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' "?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT How is that relevant to my question, which is specifically about the Configurations (with an s) element? Where is the Configurations element documented?

Comment: Please refer to [Common MSBuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022), which contains all csproj and other project files Introduction to attributes

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT Thanks, I did, but the Configurations element is not listed there. It is an essential element for managing the mapping between solution and project configurations.